# Log-based CDC with a query to stream data from source

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, oracle-cdc

I'm currently exploring on both Query based CDC and Log based CDC using Debezium connectors with Kafka connect.
With Query based CDC I could stream data when I specify specific tables or a query with joins on multiple tables in the connector configuration.

Now, trying out Log based CDC. I'm able to stream data to topics by specifying table name in the connector config
but unable to stream when I use query in the connector. Mentioned below is the connector config that I'm using.

**kafka connect config :-**

```
{
  "name": "Oracle_CDC_Customer_Ind",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "database.server.name" : "Customer-Ind",
    "database.oracle.version": "12+",
    "database.hostname" : "localhost",
    "database.port" : "1521",
    "database.user" : "C##DBZUSER",
    "database.password" : "*****",
    "oracle.jdbc.useFetchSizeWithLongColumn": "true",
    "database.schema": "c##dbzuser",
    "database.dbname" : "*****",
    "database.out.server.name" : "dbzxout",
    "database.connection.adapter": "logminer",
    "database.tablename.case.insensitive": "true",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers" : "localhost:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.customer_ind",
    "database.history.skip.unparseable.ddl": "true",
    "include.schema.changes": "true",
    "table.include.list": "C##DBZUSER.customers",
    "query": "Select * from C##DBZUSER.customers where country == 'India'",
    "snapshot.mode": "initial",
    "errors.log.enable": "true"
  }
}
```

I dont see any error in the connector logs. Should I look into any other logs or enable some logging?

Do I need to change/add properties in the connector config to stream data using query with log based CDC ?
Any pointers would be of great help.

Comment: AFAIK, queries cannot be used with log-based CDC as it will always snapshot existing data, then `tail` any table changes. If you want to filter for a certain column, you should use Kafka Streams/KSQL after the CDC data is in the topic.

Comment: @Sk Why are you using query in the Debezium source connector. Once you defined the table.include.list you will every change in data (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) not the raw data in the table itself. The flow is: After defining the Debezium Connector firstly the available data will be copied (if defined) and then it will start to capture the changes in data and replicate it into the sink/consumers.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Confluent Platform. Debezium is open source and Kafka Connect is not specific to Confluent. Please dont add the tag back.